# How to build an autograd-compatible Pytorch module that resizes tensors like images?

Tags: python-3.x, image-resizing, pytorch, tensor, resize-image

I was wondering if I can build an image resize module in Pytorch that takes a torch.tensor of 3*H*W as the input and return a tensor as the resized image.

I know it is possible to convert tensor to PIL Image and use torchvision,
but I also hope to back propagate gradients from the resized image to the original image, and the following example will return such error (in PyTorch 0.4.0 on Windows 10):

```
import numpy as np
from torchvision import transforms

t2i = transforms.ToPILImage()
i2t = transforms.ToTensor()

trans = transforms.Compose(
    t2i, transforms.Resize(size=200), i2t]
)

test = np.random.normal(size=[3, 300, 300])
test = torch.tensor(test, requires_grad=True)
resized = trans(test)
resized.backward()

print(test.grad)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Python/PyTorch/test.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/Projects/Python/PyTorch/test.py", line 33, in main
    resized = trans(test)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 42, in __call__
    img = t(img)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 103, in __call__
    return F.to_pil_image(pic, self.mode)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py", line 102, in to_pil_image
    npimg = np.transpose(pic.numpy(), (1, 2, 0))
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead.
```

It seems like I cannot "imresize" a tensor without detaching it from autograd first, but detaching it prevents me from computing gradients.

Is there a way to build a torch function/module that does the same thing as `torchvision.transforms.Resize` that is autograd compatiable? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Bilinear resize is just linear combinations of surrounding pixel values, and this operation is mathematically differentiable, it makes no sense why PyTorch cannot backpropagate its gradients...

Comment: You are probably thinking about convolutional layers? A handy example is https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/convolutional_neural_network/main.py

Comment: I feel your problem is much similar to spatial transformer network where they also learn thee affine transformation parameters.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02025.pdf

Comment: autograd only works on pytorch operations, it is not magic. under the hood, it calls a backward() function for each function and so it cant work on none pytorch functions like PIL's resize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize a PyTorch tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676688/how-to-resize-a-pytorch-tensor)

Answer (score 3):

[`torch.nn.functional.upsample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.functional.upsample.html#torch.nn.functional.upsample) works for me, ypa!

Comment: Note: this is deprecated in favour of [`torch.nn.functional.interpolate()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html#torch.nn.functional.interpolate).

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out how to preserve the gradients when implementing custom loss function.

The trick is to attach your result to the dummy gradients

```
def custom_loss(tensor1, tensor2):
    # convert tensors to PIL image, doing calculation, we have output = 0.123
    grad = (tensor1 + tensor2).sum()
    loss = grad - grad + output
    return loss
```