# How to resize a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, image-resizing, tensor

I have a PyTorch tensor of size `(5, 1, 44, 44)` (batch, channel, height, width), and I want to 'resize' it to `(5, 1, 224, 224)`

How can I do that? What functions should I use?

Comment: How do you want to resize it? By padding with `0`s? By dilating the image?

Answer (score 22):

It seems like you are looking for [`interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#interpolate) (a function in `nn.functional`):

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

x = torch.rand(5, 1, 44, 44)
out = nnf.interpolate(x, size=(224, 224), mode='bicubic', align_corners=False)
```

If you really care about the accuracy of the interpolation, you should have a look at [`ResizeRight`](https://github.com/assafshocher/ResizeRight): a pytorch/numpy package that accurately deals with all sorts of "edge cases" when resizing images. This can have an effect when directly merging features of different scales: inaccurate interpolation may result in misalignments.

Comment: just a word of warning about bicubic interpolation is that the range of the result may be wider than the range of the input. If this is important than you can use bilinear instead

Answer (score 3):

The TorchVision [`transforms.functional.resize()`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.resize) function is what you're looking for:

```py
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F

t = torch.randn([5, 1, 44, 44])
t_resized = F.resize(t, 224)
```

If you wish to use another interpolation mode than bilinear, you can specify this with the [`interpolation`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.InterpolationMode) argument.